# Alternative to logicalNot() - not doing what expected

Tags: php, typo3, extbase, typo3-6.2.x

I made a query in a EntityRepository.php file, the query goes through and gives me a number of matching entities for example:

```
100
```

My new goal is to filter out all entities which have the property `feedback.appointmentState.uid = 4`.

and when I put in this following constraint:

```
$query->equals('feedback.appointmentState.uid', 4)
```

it gives me

```
0
```

Now comes the part that I don't understand -
When I change that part to:

```
$query->logicalNot($query->equals('feedback.appointmentState.uid', 4))
```

I get

```
90
```

It's not quite working this way since it should output 100 as there are no entities that match that filter - but how can I achieve this the best way?
For clarification here my code example (of course I didn't uncomment both commented parts at the same time)

```
public function countByCompany($company) {
    $query = $this->createQuery();

    $constraints[] = $query->equals('deleted', 0);
    $constraints[] = $query->equals('hidden', 0);
    $constraints[] = $query->equals('socialworker.company', $company);

    $total = $query->matching($query->logicalAnd($constraints))->count();
// $total is 30

//        $constraints[] = $query->equals('feedback.appointmentState.uid', 4);
//        $totalCancelled = $query->matching($query->logicalAnd($constraints))->count();
// $totalCancelled is 0

//        $constraints[] = $query->logicalNot($query->equals('feedback.appointmentState.uid', 4));
//        $totalWithoutCancelled = $query->matching($query->logicalAnd($constraints))->count();
//  $totalWithoutCancelled is 15

    return false;
}
```

Comment: I will trust my instincts and say that 90 is the correct result, and you have to figure out why you expect something else.

Answer (score 0):

I dissolve your last query to

```
public function countByCompany($company) {
    $query = $this->createQuery();

    $totalWithoutCancelled = $query->matching(
        $query->logicalAnd(
            $query->equals('deleted', 0),
            $query->equals('hidden', 0),
            $query->equals('socialworker.company', $company),
            $query->logicalNot(
                $query->equals('feedback.appointmentState.uid', 4)
            )
        )
    )->count();

    return false;
}
```

Try mine. Does this the same?

```
public function countByCompany($company) {
    $query = $this->createQuery();

    $total =  $query->matching(
        $query->logicalAnd(
            $query->equals('deleted', 0),
            $query->equals('hidden', 0),
            $query->equals('socialworker.company', $company)
        ),
        $query->logicalNot(
            $query->equals('feedback.appointmentState.uid', 4)
        )
    )->count();

    return false;
}
```

Comment: I'm using a `matching` function later. I added my code, I don't know how to apply your solution, could you implement it into my code?

Comment: I changed my answer.